# Discord.js bot does everything twice

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm coding this bot for my private discord server, and I have found this bug/glitch that causes the bot to do EVERYTHING twice. In my console it also logs things twice, it answers twice. here's my code:

(I don't know if it matters but as you can see the last two commands are not there since I am currently making a command handler and I have only converted some of the commands).

UPDATE: its the next day, and now it does everything THREE times...
UPDATE #2: now when i do a command it answers with a different one... please help...

Do you know what causes it/how to fix it?

````
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = '---my token---';
var PREFIX = 'bb!';
var member



const fs = require('fs');
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(File => File.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    bot.commands.set(command.name, command);

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Discord Bot Is Online.');
    bot.user.setActivity('In BitBots FunHouse', { type: 'PLAYING'}).catch(console.error);
})


bot.on('message', msg=>{


    var args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    switch(args[0]){
        case 'Test':
            msg.channel.send('Bot Online.');
        break;





       case 'Help':
        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#FF8C00')
            .setTitle('BitBot Help Menu')
            .setAuthor('MrFishy', )
            .setDescription('BitBot Help & Commands Menu')
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Test', value: 'More test' },
                  { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
                  { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
                  { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
              )
              .addField('Test subtitle', 'Test value', true)
              .setTimestamp()
             .setFooter('All commands start with bb!', 'https://i.imgur.com/Naujnff.png');

        msg.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
        break;


       case 'Delete':
        if(!msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return msg.reply("You cannot use this command since you do not have a role with `MANAGE_MESSAGES` enabled.");
        if(!args[1]) return msg.reply("Please specify the number of messages you want to delete.");
        if(parseInt(args[1]) > 100) return msg.reply("You cannot delete more than 100 messages at once!");

        msg.channel.bulkDelete(parseInt(args[1]) + 1).then(() => {
            msg.channel.send(`Deleted ${args[1]} messages!`).then(msg.channel.delete);
        }).catch((err) => {
            return msg.reply("An error occured!")
        })
        break;

        case '8ball':
            bot.commands.get('8ball').execute(msg, args);
        break;

        case 'GetRekt':
                bot.commands.get('GetRekt').execute(msg, args);
        break;    

    }


}
)
bot.login(token);




}```

Code in one of the different command files (Just in case it helps):

```module.exports = {
    name: 'GetRekt'
    ,description: "Sends the GetRekt image.",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('Get rekt, bro. https://i.imgur.com/3qvm3d0.png');

    }
}```


Sorry if that's too much to read through, I just did not finish moving all the commands to separate files.
````

Comment: Have you made sure that you aren't running two instances of the server?

Comment: @KeithCronin how do I make sure that I'm not doing that, and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is old, but I just ran into this issue and I realized that I was running multiple terminals in vscode. I might be the only one dumb enough to make this mistake, but just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your bot is not reacting to it's own message by adding

```
if (message.author.bot) return;
```

first inside bot.on("message")

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I have found out the cause of the problem and solved it.
Turns out that I made my command handler incorrectly and caused it to run my bot multiple times. I have fixed it using [this](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files) guide from the official D.JS website.